# Django: css specificity to a webpage

Tags: css, django, static

I currently load my static files in my `base.html`. The contents of `master.css` are actually specific to one webpage. How do I load css not in the template, but in a specific webpage?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'incidents/css/master.css' %}">
```

Comment: ...just load it in that one page? What CSS applies to everything else?

Comment: does that page have a template or is it just the standard template its running off

Comment: What is the problem? You have written the right line to load css file in any page.

Comment: I don't want that css to load in any page. I only want it to load in a specific page. `base.html` is the template it's currently loaded in.

Comment: If you don't want it to load in any page, *why do you load it in `base.html`?!*

Comment: That's just how it is working now. I don't want it there. It's currently there because I can't get it load in the specific webpage i'm interested in.

Comment: Don't load it in base.html. Load it in that page only. Or make a `<style>` block in that page for only that page. You're templating something you don't want to template, so un-template and use something other than a template.

Comment: I tried putting `{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'incidents/css/master.css' %}">` in the specific webpage and removing it from my template, but it didn't work. I will try the style tags.

Comment: Why not check my answer....

Comment: I've tried both. I just want to be able load a css file in a specific html page NOT in in the template.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```html
{% if request.get_full_path = "page/url/" %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'incidents/css/master.css' %}">
{% endif %}
```

also I think you can target it by template name doing:

```html
{% if views.templateName, %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'incidents/css/master.css' %}">
{% endif %}
```

don't hold me to it I havent been on django in a while.